# Emacs. Truncate long lines

Tags: emacs, elisp

I remember I found a sample .emacs-file once, where long lines were truncated. I know about the build-in modes, but this mode behaved differently. It kept every line the same length, and didn't fill up the entire screen. Like this:

bla bla bla bla bla bla

bla bla bla bla bla bla

instead of

bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

If I end the first line with a newline (enter), then the rest of the lines follows this maximum length.

I want this because it makes it easier to read on a big widescreen monitor. Hope you understand what I mean :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, so I can just propose two modes I know:

- `auto-fill-mode` makes a newline if the line reaches 80 chars (or so)
- `visual-line-mode` makes emacs act like a "usual" text editor (w.r.t. line wrappings)

Comment: Thank you very much! auto-fill-mode was what I was looking for. Sorry for the bad explanation. Thansk again!

Answer (score 0):

You may use `fill-paragraph` to truncate long lines (select the long lines first). Its default key binding is `M-q`. Meanwhile, you can also enable `auto-fill-mode` to truncate long lines automatically.